# Finding linked objects in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to find objects in a Microsoft Word 2010 file that are linked to external files. For example, if the author has a graph linked to Excel I want to find that graph in the document. I can step through the InlineShape collection in VBA and examine the properties but have not found a way to tell me where in the document these shapes are. In other words, I would like to know, say, the page number the shape sits in. I want to ask the authors to send me the spreadsheets (typically) behind the pictures and usually want to convert most of these shapes to pictures. I can wholesale convert them to pictures in VBA but I’d rather do it one at a time so I can examine the result. Searching by hand in a large document is tedious!

I wrote the following code to display some information on linked pictures and copy the last linked picture to the clipboard. From there I can paste it into a scrap document so I know what I am looking for, but this is a crude way to do the job.

---

```
Sub Links_Finder()
' Find things that are linked elsewhere
' October 20, 2014
Dim oShape As InlineShape, n As Integer, strMsg As String
strMsg = "Found this many linked things in the document: "
n = 0
On Error Resume Next
For Each oShape In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    oShape.Select
    If oShape.Type = wdInlineShapeChart Then
        n = n + 1
        Debug.Print n
        Debug.Print oShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName
        Debug.Print oShape.LinkFormat.SourcePath
        Debug.Print oShape.LinkFormat.Type
        oShape.Select
        Selection.Copy
        strMsg = strMsg & n & vbCrLf
        strMsg = strMsg & "Copied the last one found to the clipboard"
        strMsg = strMsg & vbCrLf & oShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName
        strMsg = strMsg & vbCrLf & oShape.LinkFormat.SourcePath & vbCrLf & " Link type: " & oShape.LinkFormat.Type
        ' To break the link and insert as a picture, use this:
        'Selection.Copy
        'Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, _
            Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
    End If
Next
MsgBox strMsg
End Sub
```

Comment: `Searching by hand in a large document is tedious` Why don't you activate it? `oShape.Activate`? or Select maybe? `oShape.Select`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was pretty close to answering my own question. As L42 suggested, oShape.Activate, which was already in my code, does bring the page to the shape in question. I added some code to present the source in a message box and then ask myself if I want to stop there or continue looking. The message box appears in the document above the shape in question. My revised code is below.

```
Sub Links_Finder()
' Find things that are linked elsewhere
' October 24, 2014
Dim oShape As InlineShape, n As Integer, strMsg As String
Dim Msg, Style, Title, Response, MyString
strMsg = "Found this many linked things in the document: "
n = 0
On Error Resume Next
For Each oShape In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    oShape.Select
    If oShape.Type = wdInlineShapeChart Then
        n = n + 1
        Debug.Print n
        Debug.Print oShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName
        Debug.Print oShape.LinkFormat.SourcePath
        Debug.Print oShape.LinkFormat.Type
        oShape.Select
        Selection.Copy
        strMsg = strMsg & n & vbCrLf
        strMsg = strMsg & "Copied the last one found to the clipboard"
        strMsg = strMsg & vbCrLf & oShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName
        strMsg = strMsg & vbCrLf & oShape.LinkFormat.SourcePath & vbCrLf & " Link type: " & oShape.LinkFormat.Type

        Msg = "Source for this graphic: " & oShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName & vbCrLf
        Msg = Msg & "Do you want to continue looking?"    ' Define message.
        Style = vbYesNo ' Define buttons.
        Title = "Looking for Linked Tables"    ' Define title.
        Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)
        If Response = vbYes Then    ' User chose Yes.
            MyString = "Yes"    ' Perform some action.
        Else    ' User chose No.
            Exit For
            MyString = "No"    ' Perform some action.
        End If

        ' To break the link and insert as a picture, use this:
        'Selection.Copy
        'Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, _
            Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
    End If
Next
MsgBox strMsg
End Sub
```